# Filtering a List using contents of another List

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, filter

I have two lists. I want to filter out the first list using an element inside the second list. So I have this code:

```
 List<data> dataList = somedata;
 IEnumerable<Filter> filterList  = someFilterData;
```

and then I do the filtering using this code:

```
foreach (var s in filterList)
{
     dataList =   dataList .Where(l => l.dataId!= s.Id).ToList();     
}
```

Can someone please suggest if this is a good enough approach or how we can make it better using some other technique. Note : The list might get large so we are also thinking about performance.

Comment: i would put the filters Id inside a hashset and then do a single where, checking if dataId is not inside the hash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is to take only these items which cannot be found in the filter list. You can do it in the "old school" way, using loops:

```
foreach (var listItem in dataList)
{
    foreach (var filterItem in filterList)
    {
        if (listItem == filterItem)
        {
            dataList.Remove(listItem);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use LINQ to do the filtering:

```
dataList.Where(d => filterList.All(f => f.Id != d.dataId))
```

Comment: I like your solution. It gives the right answers and is clean. Mine solution gives the right answer but seems clunky.

Comment: @Mogsdad Thanks for raising up the problem. I read the answers in the topic from StackExchange that you linked and I agree with the things said over there. I will expand on my answer today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this, using hashset and then a single Where:

```
var filtIds = new HashSet<int>(filterList.Select(f=> f.Id));
var filteredDataList = dataList.Where(d=> !filtIds.Contains(d.dataId)).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 A more efficient approach. But he wants to filter the list so `dataList=....ToList()` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but since your filter is only known to be IEnumerable, might it not be a good idea to reify filters to prevent sucking then in from the source on each iteration?  I think this what @George is getting at.  If the source of the filters changed mid-execution, it could be inconsistent (and possible costly to re-fetch them on each iteration):

```
var filterIds = filterList.Select( f=> f.Id ).ToArray( );
```

Then, "Not any" just seems (to me) to say what you mean more than "All not equal".

```
var results = dataList.Where( d=> !filterIds.Any( f=> d==f ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need this

```
dataList = dataList.Where(l => !filterList.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(l.dataId)).ToList();
```

Comment: filterList.Contains is a wrong here. filterList is a list of filters and not a list of ids or dataIds

Comment: @AlwaysAProgrammer Thanks for comments about mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredQuery =
                from d in dataList
                let filterListIds = from f in filterList
                    select f.Id
                where filterListIds.Contains(d.DataId) == false
                select d;
```

Comment: @Mogsdad...I do not understand your comment. The answer that is accepted is also code-only. My solution is not a 'try-this' solution. I have actually coded it and it works.

Comment: @Mogsdad; thanks for the explanation. What you are saying does make perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you just want to remove all from the first list which appear in the second list and performance is important?

I like [Georges approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32013973/284240) most, it is the most efficient if the list is getting large. But `List.RemoveAll` is also more efficient:

```
dataList.RemoveAll(d => filterList.Any(x => x.ID == d.DataID));
```